# c++: I am not getting the right output (Noob Question)

Tags: c++, constructor, scope, initialization, ostream

So I am very new to C++ and I am working around with streams and member functions. I'm trying to get an output with the values im passing onto my class but i'm not getting the correct values.. Instead i get garbage values like:

```
( this is the name: , and this is the age: 3223232)
```

in the output. here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person{
    string name;
    int age;
    public:
    ostream& print_on(ostream &o) {
        return o << '( this is the name: ' << name << ', and this is the age: ' << age << ')';
    }
        Person(){
            name="noname";
            age=0;
        }
        Person(string name, int age){
            name=name;
            age=age;
        }
        void setName(string n) {
        name=n;
        }
        string getName() {
         return name;
        }
        void setAge(int a){
            age=a;
        }
        int getAge(){
            return age;
        }
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &output,Person &p);
};
 ostream& operator << (ostream &output, Person &p){
     return p.print_on(output);
 }

int main()
{
   string name="Helen";
    int age=24;

       Person p(name,age);
       cout<<p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flip to the section in your book about member initialization lists.

Comment: `return o << '( this is the name: '` etc. is a mistake, it should be double quotes around a string.  If you do not get a compiler warning or error about this then adjust your settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this constructor definition

```
    Person(string name, int age){
        name=name;
        age=age;
    }
```

the parameters hide the data members of the class with the same name.

Instead write for example

```
    Person(string name, int age){
        this->name=name;
        this->age=age;
    }
```

Or

```
    Person(string name, int age){
        Person::name=name;
        Person::age=age;
    }
```

Or a better approach is to write

```
    Person( const string &name, int age ) : name( name ), age( age )
    {
    }
```

Pay into account that you need include the header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

Also member functions that do not change the object of the class should be declared as a constant functions. For example

```
ostream& print_on(ostream &o) const
{
    //…
}
```

Also in the friend operator the second parameter also should have the qualifier const

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &output, const Person &p);
```

Comment: I'd steer away from `const std::string&` in the constructor, since either you're going to store a reference and people need to consider the lifetimes of object, or a copy needs to get made anyway. Might as well just use `std::string name`

Comment: @Tas This is the common adopted approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    Person(string name, int age){
        name=name;
        age=age;
    }
```

is wrong, you're assigning variables to themselves.

Try:

```
    Person(string p_name, int p_age){
        name = p_name;
        age = p_age;
    }
```

Comment: Small note: It's completely acceptable to use the same name if you use the member initializer list to initialize them, but honestly using different names just makes more sense anyway and is a habit worth getting into.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here

```
Person(string name, int age){
  name=name;
  age=age;
}
```

You are not setting the class variables, you are trying to set the parameters equal to themselves. To set the name and age of the person, you have to use the `this` keyword, like this:

```
Person(string name, int age) {
  this->name=name;
  this->age=age;
}
```

Comment: @Tas You are right, `this->` should be used there, I'll edit my answer, thanks!